# How does config server update configs?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

Given a spring cloud configuration server with GitHub backend.
On startup, it clones the remote repository and starts serving configs.

According to this
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/1.4.x/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_push_notifications_and_spring_cloud_bus

it is possible to set up a GitHub webhook that will push a notification to `POST /monitor` endpoint if configuration server has a 
`spring-cloud-config-monitor` dependency.

Further doc describes that config server will broadcast a message to all clients if a proper set up is in place, but I miss the part how does config server update itself?
Is it performing `git pull -f` upon receiving a webhook message?

Is it possible to tweak this behavior by implementing any kind of listener bean for example?
 This might be useful for example for filtering based on webhook message payload.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it appears that on every request configuration server checks and if necessary syncs local and remote git repos with `git pull -f`.

This behavior is defined in `JGitEnvironmentRepository.java` and starting from version 2 can be adjusted with `refreshRate` property:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-config/2.0.5.RELEASE/single/spring-cloud-config.html#_git_refresh_rate

From the other side, it has the ability to refresh configs in advance when the remote repo is updated but no client services have requested for new configs yet.
For this, it offers `POST /monitor` endpoint which can accept GitHub webhook notifications.